# What is the difference between returning jsonify() and returning make_response from in flask rest API?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

What is the difference between post methods return statement?

```py
class User(Resource):
     def post(self):
       #some functionality code
        return jsonify({'messsage':'Success','status_code':200})

class Login(Resource):
    def post(self):
       #some functionality code
        return make_response({'messsage':'Success','status_code':200})

class Resgister(Resource):
    def post(self):
       #some functionality code
        return {'messsage':'Success'},200
```

Answer (score 2):

**jsonify** creates a Response with the JSON representation of the given arguments with an application/json mimetype.
while **make_response** is used to set additional headers or can be used to convert a value in response object.

For more information read this  : [jsonify](https://kite.com/python/docs/flask.jsonify) & [make_response](https://kite.com/python/docs/flask.jsonify)

Hope this will help you! :)

Answer (score 1):

With `jsonify()` you will be able to serialize your return data and in turn return a `Response` object from Flask, though  `{'messsage':'Success'},200` will be internally converted to `Response` object too by Flask. With `make_response()` you will be able to work with rendering a view(html page or template) as a `Response` object and will be able to set headers, status codes etc.